# Merge table columns in Word 2003 or Word 2010

Tags: microsoft-word-2010, merge, microsoft-word-2003

How can I merge two table columns in Word 2003 or Word 2010?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean merge 2 (or more) table cells into one table cell, or merge the contents of 2 (or more) cells into a 3rd cell (aka concatenation)?

If its the **1st option** then simply select both (or more) cells together, right click and select `Merge`. This will result in the contents of the 2 (or more) cells being in 1 cell with a paragraph break in between each original cells content.

If its the **2nd option** then I don't think this is directly possible using Word table formulas - AFAIK you can only do numerical calculations.

You can write a macro which loops through all the rows in the table and takes the contents of columns 1 and 2, concatenates them and enters the result in column 3. This [article](http://word.tips.net/Pages/T001508_Filling_Table_Cells_with_a_Macro.html) may be a point to start from.

As an alternative, I would suggest copy/pasting the table into Excel, using Excel's CONCATENATE function and then copy/pasting back into Word.

Answer (score 2):

If you erase the column border with the Eraser, it merges each pair of cells just as you would expect. Eraser is under Table - Draw Table in Word 2003.

Comment: In more recent versions like Word 16 for Mac Eraser is in the [Table] Layout ribbon (only available while the text cursor is positioned in a table). After clicking to enable the Eraser, one can drag a narrow selection area to delete the entire division between between two columns. (It's a little finicky -- sometimes it'll also delete divisions between the cells, not just the vertical division, so this can take a couple of tries. Note that when dragging, it may highlight in red some horizontal divisions it won't really delete.) Remeber to then disable Erase.

Answer (score 0):

In Word 2010, select the cells you want, right click and hit Merge Cells.

[image]

Comment: I don't want the cells, I want the entire columns merged.

Comment: this will still work